# Value of Covariance term too high : multiple attempts to solve it

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics, covariance

I have a first array 5x1 `Bias_sp_fid` and a second one 5x1 `Bias_ph_fid` (fid for `fiducial`). I am working in astrophysics
context on an observable called '`O`' and defined by the ratio `Bias_sp` on `Bias_ph` (which are assimilated to random variables in the following).

$O = \dfrac{Bias_{sp}}{Bias_{ph}}$

To compute errors on this new observable '`O`' that I assimilate to `f(x,y)=O(Bias_sp,Bias_ph)`, I am doing a Taylor expansion up to second derivative and express the general formula for Variance on this ratio :

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(x, y) &=f(a, b)+f_{x}(a, b)(x-a)+f_{y}(a, b)(y-b) + \dfrac{f_{x x}(a, b)(x-a)^{2}}{2} \\
&+f_{x y}(a, b)(x-a)(y-b)+\dfrac{f_{y y}(a, b)(y-b)^{2}}{2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

with convention :

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f_{x} &=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\
f_{y} &=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \\
f_{x y} &=\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x \partial y} \\
f_{y x} &=f_{x y} \\
f_{x x} &=\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial^{2} x} \\
f_{y y} &=\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial^{2} y}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

Then, by applying the generale formula of Variance :

**General formula :**

By taking the random variable $z$ :

$$
z=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} x_{i}
$$
We get the following Variance for $z$ :
$$
\operatorname{Var}(z)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}^{2} \operatorname{Var}\left(x_{i}\right)+2 \sum_{i<j} a_{i} a_{j} \operatorname{cov}\left(x_{i}, x_{j}\right)
$$

**Application in my issue :** with $x\equiv Bias_{sp}$ and $y\equiv Bias_{ph}$

You can remark easily that $f_{xx}=\dfrac{d^2 O}{d^2\text{Bias$_{sp}$}} = 0$.

Here the final computation for a second order derivative :

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Var}(f(X, Y)) &=f_{x}(a, b)^{2} \operatorname{Var}(\mathrm{X})\\
&+ f_{y}(a, b)^{2} \operatorname{Var}(\mathrm{Y}) \\
&+\frac{f_{x x}(a, b)^{2}}{4} \operatorname{Var}\left((X-a)^{2}\right) \\
&+\frac{f_{y y}(a, b)^{2}}{4} \operatorname{Var}\left((Y-b)^{2}\right) \\
&+2 f_{x}(a, b) f_{y}(a, b) \operatorname{Cov}((X-a),(Y-b))\\
&+ f_{y}(a, b) f_{yy}(a, b) \operatorname{Cov}((Y),(Y-b)^2)\\
&+ f_{x}(a, b) f_{yy}(a, b) \operatorname{Cov}((X),(Y-b)^2)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

So now, I try to code the computation of each $\operatorname{Cov}$ term.

I get an anomaly on the term $f_{x}(a, b) f_{yy}(a, b) \operatorname{Cov}((X),(Y-b)^2)$. Indeed, I tried using `np.cov` function that computes the covariance between 2 1D vectors :

```
 covar_x_yy = 2*Bias_sp_fid[i]/Bias_ph_fid[i]**4 * np.cov((Bias_sp_fid,(Bias_ph_fid\
               - np.mean(Bias_ph_fid))**2))[0][1]
```

index $i$ can vary on the dimension of `Bias_sp` and `Bias_ph`, i.e from $0$ to $4$ (recall 5x1 vectors).

Here an example of values obtained for all others covariance terms (for $i=4$) :

```
var_x = 0.0003385243601431576
var_y = 1.7817901190793067e-05
var_yy = 8.528664540893595e-05
cov_x_y = -0.00015529784692005954
cov_x_yy = 0.00021074696618330292
cov_y_yy = -0.0001016068736330265
rho_correlation =  0.9997978601532392
```

You can remark the higher value for the term `cov_x_yy = 0.00021074696618330292` : that is not consistent with the following of my computation, at the level of final results (**to summarize, this high value puts the mess**).

Finally 2 questions : I don't have values of `Bias_sp` and `Bias_ph`, I have only the known values $\sigma_{\text{sp}}$ and $\sigma_{\text{ph}}$ that come from a complex code.

1. Is there a way to make appear $\sigma_{sp}$ or $\sigma_{ph}$ in the expression of covariance term `cov_x_yy` or in another covariance terms.

**As you can see, for the moment, I use the fiducial `Bias_sp_fid` and `Bias_ph_fid` as random values but I think this is not correct** : that's why I would like to insert $\sigma_{sp}$ and $\sigma_{ph}$ in my calculation since they represent characteristics (moment 2) of random variables `Bias_sp` and `Bias_ph`.

2. Do you think the covariance term used `cov_x_yy` is correct, I mean this term :

   ```
   covar_x_yy = 2*Bias_sp_fid[i]/Bias_ph_fid[i]**4 * np.cov((Bias_sp_fid,(Bias_ph_fid\
                   - np.mean(Bias_ph_fid))**2))[0][1]
   ```

   Are there others alternativs to compute this covariance term if my expression is not correct ?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You have written that "You can remark the higher value for the term cov_x_yy = 0.00021074696618330292 compared to other cov_y_yy = -0.0001016068736330265 : there is a factor ~ 20 between both" but cov_x_yy is approx magnitude 2x larger than cov_y_yy, not 20x as you state.

Comment: @user316981 . Sorry for this mistake : the problem remains, the value for `cov_x_yy = 0.00021` is still too high. What do you think about ? Are my computations correct ?